# Backup zip and transfer to FTP Backup Server an SQL-Server Express Database every hour

Tags: sql, ftp, 7zip

I need to backup an SQL-Server Express Database, zip it and transfer it to an FTP Server every hour.

So far I'm able to create the backup, but I'm not able to zip it (I tried with 7z) and transfer it but command line:

The script.sql file:

```
DECLARE @pathName NVARCHAR(512) 
SET @pathName = 'C:\prd-db-backup-' + replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar(19), getdate(), 126),'-',''),'T',''),':','') + '.bak' 
BACKUP DATABASE [Database] TO  DISK = @pathName WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Database-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

The Bat file:

```
sqlcmd -S SQLSERVER -U user -P password -i script.sql
PROBLEM1: 7z a -tzip C:\prd-db-backup-%date%%time%.zip -i! C:\prd-db-backup-%DATE%%TIME%*.bak
FTP transfer: ?
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the format of the filename of your bak file?

Comment: Hi, the format is heelp-prd-db-backup-20130729225109.bak that includes the date (YYYYMMDD) and time (HHMMSS).

Answer (score 0):

depending on your locale setting you might have to adjust this for the date/time parsing

```
rem get the last 10 chars  in either dd-mm-yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy 
set dtm=%DATE:~-10%

rem last 4 is the year
set yyyy=%dtm:~-4% 

set mm=%dtm:~4,2%
set dd=%dtm:~1,2%

set tim1=%TIME:.=%
set tim2=%tim1:,=%
rem lets just copy everyting from this date
sqlcmd -S SQLSERVER -U user -P password -i script.sql

7z a -tzip C:\prd-db-backup-%yyyy%%mm%%dd%%tim2%.zip -i! C:\prd-db-backup-%yyyy%%mm%%dd%*.bak

echo user your-ftp-username > ftpcmd.txt
echo pwd  your-ftp-password >> ftpcmd.txt
echo cd /ftp/dir/to/store >> ftmcmd.txt
echo put  C:\prd-db-backup-%yyyy%%mm%%dd%%tim2%.zip >> ftpcmd.txt
echo bye >> ftpcmd.txt

ftp -i -s:ftpcmd.txt your-ftp-server
```

Comment: Hi thanks, let me try and I will give you some feedback. Regards,